# Esper EPL Pattern A BEFORE B

Tags: esper

I'm using Esser EPL Online for getting deeper into CEP Engine Esper. Right now I'm struggling to define a EPL Statement that is true if an event happens before another event.
I want to use the "BEFORE"-Statement.

```
create schema A as (startts long, endts long) starttimestamp 'startts' endtimestamp 'endts'

create schema B as (startts long, endts long) starttimestamp 'startts' endtimestamp 'endts'

select * from A.std:lastevent() as a, B.std:lastevent() as b where a.before(b);
```

Everytime I press Submit, the following Error comes up:

Please check the EPL Module Text

Incorrect syntax near ''startts'' expecting an identifier but found QUOTED_STRING_LITERAL at line 1 column 61 [create schema A as (startts long, endts long) starttimestamp 'startts' endtimestamp 'endts' create schema B as (startts long, endts long) starttimestamp 'startts' endtimestamp 'endts' select * from A.std:lastevent() as a, B.std:lastevent() as b where a.before(b)]

Can anybody help me? Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a semicolon after each EPL statement.

```
create schema A as (startts long, endts long); // <-- Semicolon
```